# Get output from PowerShell being called by Python to be formatted like a CSV file so I can take output and put into SQL table

Tags: python, arrays, sql-server, list, powershell

new to coding, self-learning and googling a lot, but cannot find an answer specific to what I am trying to do. I will try my best to describe what I am trying to do, please let me know if you need more clarification.

Here is the code I am running to have python execute a PowerShell command and return with (3) columns of data: Application Name, Vendor, Version:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import ServerListScript

PSScriptInstalledPrograms = """Invoke-Command -ComputerName %s -ScriptBlock {
cmd.exe /c "wmic product where `"not name like '%%Windows%%' and not name like '%%Microsoft%%'`" get name, vendor, version"}"""

ListOfServers = ServerListScript.ListOfServers
server_list = ListOfServers

for server_name in server_list:
        print(PSScriptInstalledPrograms %(server_name))
        p = subprocess.run([
            "powershell.exe",
            "-command",
            PSScriptInstalledPrograms %(server_name)
        ],
        stdout=sys.stdout)
        #stdout=sys.stdout.write('\n'))
        print('Finished Processing')
```

**The ask for help part:**
What I'd like to do is to be able to take the return from Powershell and make it a CSV (or something similar) that would then be easy to put into a list  and use that list to populate a table in SQL, similar to the below (that writes the results of another python function that queries a SQL server for other results). I suspect a couple of things right off the start:

1. The return from PowerShell *looks* like a list, but is actually just displayed that way - I think that it is actually a bunch of words separated by a space and/or new line, but aren't individual items in a list; hard to explain what I mean, like the difference between:

**['Col1 row1 Col2 row1 Col3 row1 Col1  row2 Col2 row2 Col3 row2']**

vs.

**['Col1 row1'], ['Col2 row1'], ['Col3 row1'], ['Col1 row2'],['Col2 row2'],['Col3 row2']**

I hope that makes sense?

2. I am using `stdout` - but I don't know if what I am getting from the PowerShell return is actually being stored as something I can 'grab' and push somewhere else (as noted in my write to SQL table function below)

```
##Function for writing to SQL table for audit
def WriteAllMatches():
    print("Writing to [Job_Status_DB].[dbo].[Server_DB_Audit]")
    connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={%s};'
                                'Server=MYSERVER.DOMAIN.COM;'
                                'Database=Master;'
                                'uid=%s;'
                                'trusted_connection=yes' % (Driver, domain_user), timeout=4)
    cursor = connection.cursor();
    print("############### Writing Data To Table ###############")
    output = cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO [Audit_DB].[dbo].[Server_App_Audit]
                            (Server_Name,App_Name,App_Vendor,App_Version) VALUES(?,?,?,?)""",
                                AllProceedureData);
    values = [AllProceedureData]
    print(AllProceedureData)
    for row in AllProceedureData:
        print(row)
    connection.commit();
    cursor.close();
    connection.close();
```

I know that the function for writing to a SQL table for my audit will have to be modified, I just wanted to provide as much detail as possible. Also, all the print statements are for me to help figure out/understand what my code is doing (iterative approach) as I am going through this. They will *probably* be removed on the finished version.

Any help/guidance is appreciated - I am loving learning, but there are somethings that, while I can wrap my head around what I want to do, I can't seem to execute on. Please be patient with me - I spent 17 of the last 22 years being a telecom engineer and designing networks to making an attempt to learn coding/automation.

Comment: the reason your powershell code is not returning a structured object is because `wmic` is NOT powershell. it is an exe file that returns plain text. ///// have you tried the builtin PoSh cmdlet for this? take a look at `Get-Help Get-Package`.  ///// if that does not give you enuf info, then take a look at directly accessing the registry  from inside python.

Comment: Consider the facilities that are available in each language you're working with. e.g.: instead of using PowerShell to drive `wmic` via a Command Prompt shell, consider using [Get-CimInstance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) instead, e.g.: `Get-CimInstance Win32_Product -Property Name,Vendor,Version | Select-Object Name,Vendor,Version | Where-Object {-not($_.Name -like "Windows" -or $_.Name -like "Microsoft")}`. You could output that to a CSV file using `Export-Csv` for Python's consumption, or even have PowerShell insert directly into the table.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - the problem with _anything_ that touches on the  `Win32_Product` class is that it triggers a consistency check on ALL the items. that is slow ... and - worse - it **_sometimes_** triggers a reset to the default settings.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, thought that was only when using the wildcard filter?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - nope ... it turns out that ANYTHING that touches that class will trigger it. take a look at the event logs and you will see that it happens even with a filter. [*sigh ...*] lookee ... >>> Windows Installer reconfigured all applications - Windows Server | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/admin-development/windows-installer-reconfigured-all-applications <<< ///// especially at >>> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/admin-development/windows-installer-reconfigured-all-applications#more-information

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, that's odd. Towards the bottom, under *More Information*, is what threw me off. lol Same with the *caution* message in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-software-installations?view=powershell-7.2). Good to know! Will make sure to remember this... such a shame too. The class had a lot of potential.

Comment: if your setup includes the SCCM client ... then you will have the well behaved `Win32reg_AddRemovePrograms` class ... and that is safe & fast. [*grin*] otherwise, use the `*-Package` stuff if you can ... or the registry uninstall stuff if you must.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey and AlwaysLearning - thank you for the assist/feedback. I'll take a look and see what I can do, and post back the final solution when I get it. Truly appreciate the replies

Comment: @ripvw32 - you are very welcome! glad to help somewhat ... [*grin*]